# error "Foundation.h: no such file found" while compiling Objective-C on WINDOWS

Tags: objective-c, windows, compilation, foundation

iam beginner in Objective-C, i tried to compile small Hello world program to start,iam using windows vista and the shell console, my code is:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

the shell result show me the following error:

```
Foundation.h: no such file found
```

my command for compiling is:

```
gcc -o hello hello.m
```

i will appreciate any help, thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foundation, as well as NSAutoreleasePool and NSLog are part of cocoa and cocoa-touch, Apples exclusive ObjC Frameworks. While you can use Objective-C, Foundation and all Foundation classes and functions are only available on Mac OS X and iOS.

You have three choices if you want to continue working with ObjC und the classes

1. Write everything yourself (that will be hard as you say that you are a beginner and so you won't have the knowledge about the classes)
2. Use something like GNUStep which
   tries to clone Foundation
3. Switch to Mac OS X

Comment: That`s it, the "GNUstep" packages, i have already installed it and i have added an environment variables which is: C:\GNUstep\mingw\bin\gcc.exe but the code still unable to compile successfully :(, the Foundation folder does exist under: C:\GNUstep\GNUstep\System\Library\Headers

Answer (score 3):

Try writing this to your command line. I had the same problem and it worked for me.

```
gcc -I"c:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers" -L "c:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries" -o hello hello.m -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I searched the entire Stack Overflow and finally find answer here.